# Amadeus Flight API implementation using curl

Tags: curl, amadeus

I want to use Amadeus Flight API using curl. So help me to implement the api using core PHP. If you can provide me with all three example(get, post, put, delete) of rest api in php that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My employer (dahabtours GmbH) has agreed to release our API wrapper Class in order to give something back to the opensource community, since there is no official PHP SDK yet. This makes using the self-service API in PHP a lot easier.

https://github.com/dahabtours/amadeus-php-sdk

```
$amadeus_api = new AmadeusDahabtours\SelfServiceApiClient({CLIENT_ID}, {CLIENT_SECRET});

$amadeus_results = $amadeus_api->lowFares([
    'origin'        => 'FRA',
    'destination'   => 'CAI',
    'departureDate' => '2019-07-15',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of php with curl doing the authorisation (so a POST). To get your **API Key** and your **API Secret** you can follow the [Get Started Guide](https://developers.amadeus.com/quick-start-guide/category?id=77&durl=335&parentId=NaN)

```
$url = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token';
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=API_KEY&client_secret=API_SECRET');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$token = curl_exec($curls);
curl_close($curls);
print_r ($token);
```

You will need to get the access_token from the previous call to add it in the header of the next one. This is an example of a call to the Flight Inspiration API (don't forget to replace **access_token**):

```
$url = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=MAD';
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer access_token'));
$result = curl_exec($curls);
    if (curl_errno($curls)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curls);
    }
print_r ($result);
curl_close ($curls);
```

If you want more examples you can look at the [Postman collection](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2672636/RWEcPfuJ#1ab5d01a-cd49-9791-089e-1333f216c42d), switch the language to PHP and get the examples on the right panel (don't forget to add the header):

> CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Bearer access_token'),

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on PHP Curl and also will work all type of APIs environment:

```php
$wsdl='.....';  


$nonceBase=generateSomewhatRandomString();

$userId='XXXXXXXX';

$officeId='XXXXXXXXX';

$Pass=base64_encode('XXXXXXXX');

$messageId=generateGuid();

 $password = base64_decode($Pass);

            $creation = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

            $t = microtime(true);

            $micro = sprintf("%03d", ($t - floor($t)) * 1000);

            $creationString = createDateTimeStringForAuth($creation, $micro);

            $messageNonce = generateUniqueNonce($nonceBase, $creationString);

            $encodedNonce = base64_encode($messageNonce);

            $digest = generatePasswordDigest($password, $creationString, $messageNonce);

 $SOAP_API_URL='https://nodeD2.test.webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXXXXXXXX';

$action='http://webservices.amadeus.com/XXXXXXXXXX';

$actionLast='XXXXXXXXXX';   

            $soapXML='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xml.amadeus.com/'.$actionLast.'" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns5="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns2:MessageID>'.$messageId.'</ns2:MessageID><ns2:Action>'.$action.'</ns2:Action><ns2:To>https://nodeD2.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWQTC1QI</ns2:To><oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><oas:UsernameToken xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" Id="UsernameToken-1"><oas:Username>'.$userId.'</oas:Username><oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'.$encodedNonce.'</oas:Nonce><oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">'.$digest.'</oas:Password><oas1:Created>'.$creationString.'</oas1:Created></oas:UsernameToken></oas:Security><ns5:AMA_SecurityHostedUser><ns5:UserID POS_Type="1" PseudoCityCode="'.$officeId.'" AgentDutyCode="SU" RequestorType="U"/></ns5:AMA_SecurityHostedUser></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body>'.$wsdl.'</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
';

$soapUser=$userId;

$soapPassword=$Pass;

$headers = [
        "Content-type: application/xml",
        'SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"'
    ];
     $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$SOAP_API_URL);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $soapXML);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
$your_xml_response = html_entity_decode($data);
$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:', 'awsse:', 'wsa:'], '',$your_xml_response);
$clean_xml = str_ireplace(['&'], '&amp;', $clean_xml);
$Results = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);
```